# Basic issue about Cmake

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, mingw

Im trying to use OpenCV but I keep on getting this error on Cmake:

> CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MinGW Makefiles"

I know what I have to do is : "cmake is having a hard time finding make and GCC, add the mingw bin dir to your PATH environment variable."

But I do not know:

1. how to add the mingw
2. where is the PATH environment variable?

Comment: Im on windows, but its boot camped from mac

Could that be an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This link](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) describes how to add entries to the PATH environmental variable. You need to add the directory where your MinGW is installed there.

You can also consult [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29) if you want some information what PATH is actually for.